# What does Acunetix Aspect enabled mean in the report

Tags: http-headers

I was just going through the report generated by Acunetix online. And I was just curious to understand what does Acunetix-aspect header mean?

Below are two header added by Acunetix. Can someone please explain these.

```
Acunetix-Aspect-Password: 082119f75623eb7abd7bf357698ff66c
Acunetix-Aspect: enabled
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the `Acunetix-Aspect: enabled` HTTP header is present it means that [Acunetix AcuSensor](https://www.acunetix.com/vulnerability-scanner/acusensor-technology/) is in use.

AcuSensor works by placing a sensor on the back-end of your application for the scanner to communicate with during a scan, making that scan a 'gray-box scan' rather than just a black-box scan. This allows the scanner to confirm vulnerabilities and even do a back-end crawl since it has access to the source code of the application.

Naturally, there needs to be some kind of authentication between the scanner and the application, therefore AcuSensor uses a password to accomplish this (since you're using the online version of the scanner, this password is automatically generated for you), which is why you're also seeing the `Acunetix-Aspect-Password` HTTP header.

---

In summary, if you have AcuSensor installed on your application, the scanner needs to send these two headers (with the correct password) to be able to communicate with the sensor on the back-end of your app.

Comment: Awesome. I did google and read manual but it was not as clear as your answer :)